# Starting pentaho after first installation

Tags: tomcat, pentaho

Hi I just downloaded the latest version of pentaho. When I try starting it for the first time I get this error. Please help

```
root@rumbylove:/opt/Pentaho/biserver-ce# ./start-pentaho.sh
/opt/Pentaho/biserver-ce
/opt/Pentaho/biserver-ce
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java
Cannot find ./catalina.sh
This file is needed to run this program
```

Comment: well does catalina.sh exist? also not sure the bi server has been tested and whether it even works or not with Java 7.  Err, actually, 1.7, whats that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The java location is a common source of problems. If the java.exe file is not found, you can change the environment variable (PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME). If this environment variable does not exist, you should create it as a new system environment variable. You should set PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME to the java path. You can find the java path by clicking the View button in the Java tab of the Java Control Panel.